# How to programmatically digital sign PDF document?

Tags: c#, java, pdf, certificate, signing

I need to digitally sign PDF documents from Java or C#.
I've found iText, is it a good solution? are there any others?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried iText once and it was quite easy to implement in a C# solution. I have not tried other solutions. Esp. I could not find any proper free (no-cost) solutions.

Answer (score 0):

See PDFBox at apache, used in conjunction with BouncyCastle it will do what you require.

Comment: I've used iText successfully, now i'm trying pdfbox, but i have some problems. keystore and cert was created with java keytool (from itext example)
After running:  org.apache.pdfbox.PDFBox Encrypt -certFile test-cert.cer -canModify false -canPrint false test.pdf test-signed-out.pdf

Encrypt failed with the following exception:
org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException: Cannot find any provider supporting 1.2.840.10040.4.1